# How do channels distribute evenly to multiple goroutines

Tags: go

I have this code to upload a maximum of 30 files at any given time (there could be thousands of files needing to be uploaded).  Everything works exactly like I want it to: the goroutines take a file from the tasks, uploads it, and onto the next.

My question is: why don't the goroutines upload the same files?  I've tested this and it seems like a file is never uploaded twice.  Are the channels doing a round robin?

```
tasks := make(chan string, 10000)
var wg sync.WaitGroup

// create a limited number of routines
routineLimit := 30
for i := 0; i < routineLimit; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        // check to see if there is a new task
        for file := range tasks {
            Upload(file) // upload the file
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()
}

// get the files
files := GetFilePaths()
for _, file := range(files) {
        // add the file to the queue of tasks
    tasks <- file
}

wg.Wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

When there are multiple receivers for a single channel as in your example, input will be received in a random order.

Comment: But the file only goes to one goroutine, right?

Comment: Yes. Channels don't broadcast messages, only goes to one listener.